# cronjob not executed

Tags: cron

I have a problem running a cronjob. No experience with it, so probably overseeing something nooby. The following script works like a charm (all old filters are deleted from db) when run from the shell:

```
dude@linux:~> /usr/bin/env /home/dude/RubyOnRails/myproject/script/rails runner /home/dude/RubyOnRails/myproject/script/delete_old_filters.rb
```

I made the script executable with chmod. Now I want this to run regularly using a cronjob:

```
dude@linux:~> crontab -e
```

This file was empty, and I placed this on a single line:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/env /home/dude/RubyOnRails/myproject/script/rails runner /home/dude/RubyOnRails/myproject/script/delete_old_filters.rb
```

I expect the script to run every minute, but nothing happens. In /etc/cron.deny, only 'guest' is mentioned, and /etc/allow does not exist. Restarting my system did not help as well.

The crontab seems to be updated proberly:

```
dude@linux:~> crontab -l
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.f9Et2M installed on Thu May  3 14:04:47 2012)
# (Cronie version 4.2)
* * * * * /usr/bin/env /home/dude/RubyOnRails/myproject/script/rails runner /home/dude/RubyOnRails/myproject/script/delete_old_filters.rb
```

But I expected here a bit as well:

```
dude@linux:~> atq
dude@linux:~>
```

The cronjob does something. Every minute an entry is added to /var/log/cron.log:

```
2012-05-03T15:27:01+02:00 linux /USR/SBIN/CRON[5276]: (dude) CMD (/usr/bin/env /home/dude/RubyOnRails/myproject/script/rails runner /home/dude/RubyOnRails/myproject/script/delete_old_filters.rb)
```

The problem is, that the job is not executed. It should remove some records from the database, but it doesn't. Running the same script manually does the trick.

Anyone seeing the (perhaps trivial) thing that I missed?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? That the operation is not performed or that you don't see it on the screen? Since crontab operations run at the background.

Comment: Thanks for your response and sorry for being unclear. I have edited the question (problem is that it is not performed, no need to see it on the screen).

Comment: Have you checked the cron logs? you need to activate it first (e.g. with debian: http://happy-coding.com/enable-crontab-logging-in-debian-linux/)

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, this got me a step further. I did not have the log on, but I have now. Something happens, but it does not change my database. I added the log to my question.

Comment: Take a look here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9466/15142

Comment: `atq` only shows jobs scheduled using the `at` scheduler, not cron. Check your mail on the Linux system; cron will send you the output of the command. If there are errors, they may appear in the message.

Comment: This may be a better question for Server Fault or unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help, using the brackets.

`* * * * *` ( *colon separated commands-to-execute* )

Check it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but it did not help. There are two pair of brackets now, so it seems to automatically add brackets already.

Comment: Everything else seems fine. Please analyze the execution you are doing .i.e. be sure the data is present which is to be deleted. Or do some trivial file writing in the ruby file to be sure the process is executing the call.